# The Japanese for "bonded joint"

Tags: words, english-to-japanese

Could someone tell me how I'd say "bonded joint"?

The context that it is pointing to a diagram showing a bike frame has titanium joints bonded to it.

Comment: I think it might be 接合継手.

Comment: Thanks! If I was going to go on to say there is a high capacity at the joints would I use 接合　again？

Comment: My craft knowledge is practically zero. I'd have to do some research to figure it out. You could use weblio or linguee to look up technical terms.

Comment: I guess 接合部 would work if you are referring to the welded  joint.

Answer (score 1):

According to [weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/bonded+joint), the Japanese for 'bonded joint' is 接合継手. If you take a look at [this page](https://astamuse.com/ja/published/JP/No/2016056840) for 接合継手, you can check the images to see if they are indeed showing a bonded joint.

My [linguee search](http://www.linguee.com/english-japanese/search?source=auto&query=load%20capacity) for high load capacity (which I assume applies to joints) came up with the word 高負荷容量. The English sentences suggested the word was being used in the context you want. If you just want to refer to the joint itself, the word is 継手.

Comment: I can confirm this is an acceptable translation. I have translated the term many times.